# Comprobar array abcedario hasta que tenga que volver atrás PHP

Tags: php, array

```
<?php

$abc = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","x","y","z");
$valores = array("luna","sol","abrir","acceso");

$contador = 0;
$result = array();

foreach ($valores as $value){

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); $i++) {

        $letra = $value[$i];

        for($z = 0; $z < sizeof($abc); $z++){

            if($abc[$z] === $letra){

                echo $letra; // Debug

            }

        }

    }
    $contador++;

}
```

Tengo este código que comprueba que cada letra de cada  palabra del array  **valores** contra el array **abc**. En `echo letra` printeo por pantalla el resultado **lunasolabriracceso**. Lo comprueba bien, en ese mismo trozo de código quiero hacer lo que voy a explicar a continuación y no se por donde empezar.

Como veis hay un array **result** que no se esta usando en ningun momento. *En ese array quiero guardar las palabras luna, sol ....* del array **valores** pero con la condicion solo guarde hasta que en el array **abc** no tenga que volver atras en el diccionario.

Asi que el resultado deberia ser:

> lun, s, abr, acces

No se si me explicado del todo bien, ya que es algo complejo de explicar. Si hay alguna duda intentare expresarme mejor. No se como empezar hacer esto. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno según logré entender es que quieres que se armen nuevas palabras según el orden del abecedario y cuando una letra no coincida con el orden se detenga y pase a la otra palabra.

Hice algunas modificaciones a tu código, lo dejo comentado para que comprendas lo que hice, de todas formas si tienes dudas no dudes en consultarme.

Aquí el código:

```
$abc = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","x","y","z");
$valores = array("luna","sol","abrir","acceso");
$result = array(); // Variable para almacenar las nuevas paabras

foreach ($valores As $valor) {
    $indexABC = 0; // Declaramos el indexABC para controlar que el abcdario solo se inicie una vez por palabra
    $nuevaPalabra = ''; // Aqui se almacena la palabra armada sin el retroceso del abcdario
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($valor); $i++) {
        $letra = $valor[$i];
        while ($indexABC < count($abc)) {
            if ($letra == $abc[$indexABC]) {
                $nuevaPalabra .= $letra; // Concatenamos la letra encontrada
                break; // Una vez encontramos la letra con esto pasamos a la siguiente (Cortamos el ciclo while)
            }
            $indexABC++;
        }
    }
    $result[] = $nuevaPalabra; // Agregamos las palabras armadas a la variable result
}

print_r($result); // Finalmente mostramos el array de resultado
```

Salida:

> Array ( [0] => lu [1] => s [2] => abr [3] => acces )

Solo una observación en tu ejemplo pones que el resultado de **luna** deberia ser **lun** pero lo correcto seria **lu** ya que **n** se encuentra antes que **u**.

Saludos. ;)

Comment: Perfección!!! Muchismas gracias, es justo lo que quería hacer.